# Sliding down the bottom of a div in a grid, without sliding the entire row.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working with a grid structure using CSS. Within the grid there are panels within each panel there is a button and at the bottom there is a hidden div.

When the button is clicked the hidden div slides down (using jQuery slideToggle). There are multiple panels in the rows and columns.

I have an issue that when the button is clicked to slide down then the entire row slides down - not just the row directly below!

How do I get it to only slide down the panel below it, rather than the whole next row?

I have created a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/873688/

Here is the code I have been trying to get working!

Thanks!

HTML

```
<div id="expand-box">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="handlebars-sandbox">

      <div class="panel">
      <div class="title">HELLO WORLD</div>
      <div class="button"><button>OPEN</button></div>
      <div id='reveal-container'> BOTTOM</div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel">
      <div class="title">HELLO WORLD</div>
      <div class="button"><button>OPEN</button></div>
      <div id='reveal-container'> BOTTOM</div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel">
      <div class="title">HELLO WORLD</div>
      <div class="button"><button>OPEN</button></div>
      <div id='reveal-container'> BOTTOM</div>
      </div>

       <div class="panel">
      <div class="title">HELLO WORLD</div>
      <div class="button"><button>OPEN</button></div>
      <div id='reveal-container'> BOTTOM</div>
      </div>

    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.panel {
  border: 1px solid black; 
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px; 
  text-align: center;}

#reveal-container {
  display:none;
  height: 30px}

#expand-box {
    width: 65%;
    margin: 0 auto;}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;}

.title{
  height: 80px}

#handlebars-sandbox {
  padding: 8px;
  display: grid;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(350px, 1fr)) ;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px
}

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }

  #handlebars-sandbox {
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(360px, 1fr) ) ;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(300px, auto);
  }
}

@supports (display: grid) {
  .wrapper > * {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

JS

```
/* REVEALS REVEAL CONTAINER*/
$(document).on('click', '.button', function () {
  $(this).parents('.panel').find('#reveal-container').slideToggle()

});
```

Comment: Please do not duplicate ID's they should always be unique. `reveal-container`

Answer (score 1):

All what you need to do is change id='reaveal-container' to class. ID has to be unique. It can perform once on the page. When I changed it on to class, everything works perfectly.

```js
/* REVEALS REVEAL CONTAINER*/
$(document).on('click', '.button', function () {
  $(this).parents('.panel').find('.reveal-container').slideToggle()

});
```

```css
.panel {
  border: 1px solid black; 
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px; 
  text-align: center;}

.reveal-container {
  display:none;
  height: 30px}

#expand-box {
    width: 65%;
    margin: 0 auto;}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;}

.title{
  height: 80px}

#handlebars-sandbox {
  padding: 8px;
  display: grid;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(350px, 1fr)) ;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px
}

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }

  #handlebars-sandbox {
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(360px, 1fr) ) ;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(300px, auto);
  }
}

@supports (display: grid) {
  .wrapper > * {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="expand-box">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="handlebars-sandbox">

      <div class="panel">
      <div class="title">HELLO WORLD</div>
      <div class="button"><button>OPEN</button></div>
      <div class='reveal-container'> BOTTOM</div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel">
      <div class="title">HELLO WORLD</div>
      <div class="button"><button>OPEN</button></div>
      <div class='reveal-container'> BOTTOM</div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel">
      <div class="title">HELLO WORLD</div>
      <div class="button"><button>OPEN</button></div>
      <div class='reveal-container'> BOTTOM</div>
      </div>

       <div class="panel">
      <div class="title">HELLO WORLD</div>
      <div class="button"><button>OPEN</button></div>
      <div class='reveal-container'> BOTTOM</div>
      </div>

    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - But this hasn't solved it! Copied your changes to a new fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/67xjhLme/. Behaves the same! I understand though that I need to change the ID to Class. Do you have another other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Carsten Løvbo Andersen is right, ID'should be unique, an switched to classes, it can cause errors.
What I think you are confusing for the next row opening is not the the ID or jQuery, but really the fault of the CSS you are using.

```
#handlebars-sandbox {
  padding: 8px;
  display: grid;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(350px, 1fr)) ;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px
}
```

You are confusing revealing with boarders and margins, its not revealing the next one its just that the margin and borders of each panel are linked to each other because you are using display: grid; on #handlebars-sandbox, it kinda like having inline-block.

What I suggest is a putting a min-height: 130px; under .panel or just get rid of grid and do it with dispaly:block which it be a little harder.

Comment: Thanks Mark! I need the grid as I have a lot of results and I need it to organise my results for it to be responsive. Just to clarify we are talking about the same thing I found this: http://jsfiddle.net/nbFkZ/4/. When the user hover it sends the div down. Mine is slightly different however in this the panel directly below it opens!